# Azure DevOps - Automating default 'original estimate' field value for individual child work items

Tags: azure-devops

Looking for some help. I have a parent campaign work item (user story) that when created auto populates child work items in the template. What I want to do is choose the sizing and have each size dictate what the original estimate default will be in those child work items.

For example, if I chose large size, the original estimate in child work item for build will be 10, the original estimate for QA child work item will be 8, the original estimate for deploy child work item will be 5.

I have no idea where to start. Thanks in advance!

I tried triggers but didn't see the correct options to create this scenario.

Comment: I don't think this is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your description, you are trying to automate the process of populating child work items based on the size of a parent work item in Azure DevOps. Azure DevOps doesn’t support this feature directly.

You can use [power automate](https://make.powerautomate.com/) to achieve your expectation.

Please check the similar link [Copying values from Parent to Child WorkItems in Azure DevOps using a PowerAutomate Flow](https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/copying-values-from-parent-to-child-workitems-in-azure-devops-using-a-powerautomate-flow/). You can parse the parent work item details to get the `size` field value, add a Condition action to check the value of the size field, if it's large, create the child work item accordingly.

For example, to create child work item, you can add `Link url` and `Link type`(Hierarchy-reverse, it's childlink), specify the `Original Estimate` value:

[image]

Child work item added:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Backtracking a bit. This ADO was set up for me. I have no idea how they got the parent ticket to autopopulate the child tickets when when created in the first place. Is thi set up in power automate also? I want to try to duplicate this for another work item type.

Comment: Yes, it's setup in power automate. If you want to duplicate another work item, you need to avoid infinite loop by conditions, as child work item is same type. You can raise a new ticket to power-automate tag to get it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a conditional action based on the value of a field on the task, but there's no way to define a rule based on the value of a field in a linked (e.g. parent) work item.

However, you could create a [service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops) on "Work Item Created" or "Work Item Updated" to call a script that uses the API.